# Can create zip archive in PHP, but cannot download it correctly2

Tags: php, download, zip

I want to comment for this post "[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253982/can-create-zip-archive-in-php-but-cannot-download-it-correctly)" , but my reputation is lower tan 50, so I have to ask nearly the same question again.

I get the following error message from unzip (after downloading it from my website).

> End-of-central-directory signature not found. Either this file is not
> a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive. In the
> latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
> the last disk(s) of this archive. unzip: cannot find zipfile directory
> in one of foo.zip or foo.zip.zip, and cannot find foo.zip.ZIP, period.

On my lampp server (testsetup) (at /opt/lampp/myprojects/tmp/foo.zip) unzip works perfect ( no error messages).

I am using this code:

```
$filename = 'foo.zip';
$path = '/opt/lampp/myprojects/tmp/foo.zip';
if(!file_exists($path))
{
    die('Error: file not found');
}
else {
    $handle = fopen($path, "r");
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/zip');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));

    flush();
    readfile($path);
    fclose($handle);
```

Can anybody see my mistake and help me to solve this problems? I am trying to fix it for about 5h but I am not able to solve the problem.

Comment: Comment out `$handle = fopen($path, "r");` and `fclose($handle);` leaving just the `readfile($path);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following to send your ZIP file to the user/browser. No reason to open it first.

```
ob_end_clean();
$FileBytes = filesize($temp_file);

header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="WhateverYourFileNameIs.zip"');
header('Content-Length: ' . $FileBytes);

readfile($temp_file);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$filename = 'foo.zip';
$path = '/tmp/foo.zip';
if(!file_exists($path)) {
    die('Error: file not found');
}

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));

readfile($path);
```